# Find type, vertex, focus, and directrix of the conic with equation $x^2-2\sqrt {3}xy+3y^2+y=0$

Tags: conic-sections

> Given the conic section equation
>
> $$x^2-2\sqrt {3}xy+3y^2+y=0$$
>
> determine its type, and find its vertex, focus, and  directrix.

My try :

$$\text{discriminant} = B^2-4AC=12 - 4\cdot 1\cdot 3 = 0$$

since $\text{discriminant}=0$ , the conic section is a **parabola**.

> Now, how can I write the above parabola in standard form so that I can get all needed information?

Thank you

Comment: $4((y+\frac1{16})^2+(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16})^2-(\frac12 y+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x -\frac18)^2)$ simplifies to your equation, meaning the focus is $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16},-\frac1{16})$ and the directrix is $\frac12 y+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac18=0$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$
x^2−2\sqrt3xy+3y^2=(x-\sqrt3y)^2=
4\left(x\cos{\pi\over3}-y\sin{\pi\over3}\right)^2.
$$
The expression inside the last parentheses is the resulting $x$ coordinate when point $(x,y)$ is rotated by $\pi/3$ counterclockwise. Introducing then the rotated coordinates:
$$
X=x\cos{\pi\over3}-y\sin{\pi\over3},
\quad
Y=y\cos{\pi\over3}+x\sin{\pi\over3},
$$
your equation becomes
$$
Y=-8X^2+\sqrt3X,
$$
which is in standard form.
You can then find focus, vertex, and so on, for this parabola and then rotate back by $-\pi/3$ to the original $(x,y)$ coordinate system.